# Write a variable's data as it is in ADLS file

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I want to write the content of a variable that is created dynamically in the program to a ADLS file.
This is how I am getting the data -

```
@dataclass
class pipeline_run:
    id:str
    group_id:str
    run_start:str
    run_end:str
    pipeline_name:str
    pipeline_status:str
    parameters:str
    message:str
    addl_properties:str    

runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(rg_name, df_name,
                                                     filter_parameters={'lastUpdatedBefore': 'date'})

    #Array to hold the pipeline run returns
    list_of_json_data = list()
    
    for i in range(0, len(runs.value)):
        this_run = runs.value[i]

        #Gathering each runs information and storing into dataclass
        data = pipeline_run(this_run.run_id, this_run.run_group_id, this_run.run_start, this_run.run_end, this_run.pipeline_name, 
                            this_run.status, this_run.parameters, this_run.message, this_run.additional_properties)

    #Converting dataclass to dict and storing in the created list
    list_of_json_data.append(asdict(data))
```

Now, I want *list_of_json_date* to write in an ADLs File (.json). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `list_of_json_data` is a list of dictionary, right? and did you get the output for the above code? if yes, can you share a sample of this data that you got from the above code?

Comment: yes, it is list of dicts - here when i run this code to print _list_of_json_data_

`[{'id': 'xx', 'group_id': 'xxx', 'run_id': 'xxxx',...},{},{},...]`

Comment: where are you executing the above code in Azure Synapse or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that, Yes it is in Azure Synapse Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have list of dictionaries as variable, follow the below approach to achieve your requirement.
First Create an ADLS Gen2 Linked Service in Synapse.

Then Mount your Target container using the Linked service.

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
"abfss://<container_name>@<Storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
"/<Mountpoint_name>",
{"linkedService":"<Linked_service_name>"}
)
```

[image]

After mounting, you can do it either by using **Pyspark dataframe and pandas** or **`with open()` and `json` in python**. Use the mount point in building the file path.

**Using Pyspark dataframe and pandas:**

Here I have used a sample list of dictionaries as the variable `list_of_json_data`.

Code:

```
list_of_json_data=[{"id": "24", "group_id": "1224", "run_id": "990b0720-4747-4992-b87f-a74e1078a5f1"},
{"id": "16", "group_id": "1216", "run_id": "990b0720-4747-4992-b87f-a74e1078a5f1"},
{"id": "20", "group_id": "2408", "run_id": "990b0720-4747-4992-b87f-a74e1078a5f1"}]

#Create spark dataframe with variable
df = spark.createDataFrame(list_of_json_data)
display(df)

#Get the spark Job Id to build the path
jobid=mssparkutils.env.getJobId()

#Building the path
LogFilepath='/synfs/'+jobid+'/sourcedata/Sample2.json'
print(LogFilepath)

#Write to JSON path
df.toPandas().to_json(LogFilepath,orient='records')
```

[image]

**Result JSON file:**

[image]

**Using `with open()` and `json`:**

Use the below code:

```
import json

#get the spark Job Id to build File path
jobid=mssparkutils.env.getJobId()
Filepath='/synfs/'+jobid+'/sourcedata/PipelinesJSON.json'

#Write to JSON Path
with  open(Filepath, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_of_json_data , f)
```

[image]

**Result JSON file:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @Rakesh , this worked perfect for me, I have done using pyspark df and pandas